# One hot encoding categorical features to use as training data with numerical features in sklearn

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to train a model that reads data from a csv as the training data. To do this I am trying to conduct one hot encoding on the categorical features, and then pass the resulting arrays of 1s and 0s in as features, along with just the vanilla numerical features.

I have the following code:

```
X = pd.read_csv('Data2Cut.csv')

Y = X.select_dtypes(include=[object])

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

Y_2 = Y.apply(le.fit_transform)


enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()

enc.fit(Y_2)

onehotlabels = enc.transform(Y_2).toarray()
onehotlabels.shape

features = []
labels = []
mycsv = csv.reader(open('Data2Cut.csv'))
indexCount = 0
for row in mycsv:
  if indexCount < 8426:
    features.append([onehotlabels[indexCount], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[6], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11]])
    labels.append(row[12])
    indexCount = indexCount + 1

training_data = np.array(features, dtype = 'float_')
training_labels = np.array(labels, dtype = 'float_')

log = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
log = log.fit(training_data, training_labels)
joblib.dump(log, "modelLogisticRegression.pkl")
```

It seems to be getting to the line:

```
training_data = np.array(features, dtype = 'float_')
```

Before it crashes giving the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I figure this is a result of the one hot encoded values being arrays and not floats. How can I change/tweak this code to handle the categorical and numerical features as training data?

Edit: an example of a row i am feeding in, where each column is a feature is:

```
mobile, 1498885897, 17491407,   23911,  west coast, 2,  seagull, 18,    41.0666666667,  [0.325, 0.35],  [u'text', u'font', u'writing', u'line'],    102, 5  
#...
```

Comment: tried this but it gave the same error

Comment: Can you provide a bit of your data? It would be helpful to debug.

Comment: added a sample row!

Comment: This is from PostData2Cut or Data2Cut? How is the latter relevant? Can you post that too?

Comment: my bad - wrong name i copied in - both are Data2Cut.csv - still same error.

Comment: Actually, `onehotlabels[indexCount]`, `row[9]`, and `row[10]` are all lists.

Comment: Furthermore, `row[10]` holds strings. You can't even convert those to floats.

Comment: yeah i tried the flatten and it gave the same error. so i am approaching this all wrong then?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you're appending strings to your feature list. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the strings are just categories, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You must have already found your answer, but I am posting my findings (I was struggling with the same) here for people who have the same question. The way to achieve this is to append the columns of the resulting encoded sparse matrix to your training dataframe instead. E.g. (ignore the mistake in the price in the first row):

[image: Source: https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f]

This is of course a practical solution if you do not have too many unique values in your categories. You could look into more advanced encoding methods such as [Backward Difference Coding](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/backward_difference.html) or [Polynomial Coding](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/polynomial.html) for cases where your categorical features can take many different values.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of sklearn are you using?

I see that in sklearn version 0.18.1 , passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated and gives a warning as below and does not give the desired result.

DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)

Try replacing the following line of code

```
onehotlabels = enc.transform(Y_2).toarray()
```

to one below

```
onehotlabels = enc.transform(Y_2.reshape((-1,1)).toarray()
```

or you may use `pd.get_dummies` to get the one hot coded feature matrix.